# how to return the same object after "merge" transformation as it was at the beginning

Tags: r

I have a `list` with an arbitrary number of elements (3 in this example)
each element is a `xts` object with an arbitrary number of `rows`

```
My_list
```

..

```
$Sec1
                         Open     High       Low     Close
2016-01-01 00:02:00  96.81493 103.8074  96.48305  99.31684
2016-01-01 00:03:00 100.31574 100.9088  95.27193  95.27193
2016-01-01 00:04:00  95.11235 105.5243  95.11235 105.41863
2016-01-01 00:05:00 105.85303 117.9486 104.51442 117.94861
2016-01-01 00:06:00 118.60936 121.7275 116.02890 118.76587
2016-01-01 00:07:00 118.96981 119.5623 111.49401 118.46579
2016-01-01 00:10:00 115.68374 115.6837 102.88741 108.07260
2016-01-01 00:12:00 101.51486 102.4733  97.82271  99.14294
2016-01-01 00:13:00  98.81746 103.8946  90.79351 103.89463
2016-01-01 00:15:00 100.47314 100.4731  84.78741  94.06465
2016-01-01 00:16:00  94.94257 107.0833  94.12961 102.15526
2016-01-01 00:17:00 101.74539 104.1814  92.38105  92.42347

$Sec2
                         Open      High       Low     Close
2016-01-01 00:01:00  98.37414  99.96370  90.72532  92.95577
2016-01-01 00:02:00  93.98500  93.98500  73.69129  80.18034
2016-01-01 00:04:00  76.43040  78.95213  65.05842  65.61655
2016-01-01 00:05:00  64.99275  75.81193  63.17524  74.69825
2016-01-01 00:06:00  72.37924  83.95192  72.37924  83.95192
2016-01-01 00:08:00  81.29073  83.81830  75.01105  80.61681
2016-01-01 00:12:00 106.27114 109.24152  98.20000 102.32379
2016-01-01 00:17:00 103.73324 109.78397 103.73324 107.02864

$Sec3
                         Open      High       Low     Close
2016-01-01 00:01:00  99.85170 109.91461  99.85170 107.31518
2016-01-01 00:02:00 106.66197 115.44153 104.47501 109.24811
2016-01-01 00:03:00 110.84442 118.38943 110.83901 113.95159
2016-01-01 00:04:00 114.71170 118.63914 107.73243 114.53394
2016-01-01 00:06:00 106.73027 108.71359 101.05015 101.42198
2016-01-01 00:07:00  99.97737 110.32388  98.99063 106.02683
2016-01-01 00:08:00 105.86289 114.69850 103.34898 110.09985
2016-01-01 00:09:00 110.25313 111.33632  99.71466 111.33632
2016-01-01 00:10:00 112.03636 117.08576 111.28522 111.69231
2016-01-01 00:12:00  93.97850 100.14015  83.35741  83.35741
2016-01-01 00:13:00  82.28654  89.93466  81.26308  85.61102
2016-01-01 00:15:00  82.10802  82.10802  70.98550  74.15053
2016-01-01 00:16:00  74.56891  78.30949  73.06504  77.90111
```

then i apply `merge` function to `My_list`

```
Merge_list <- do.call(merge,My_list)
```

..

```
 Merge_list
                         Open     High       Low     Close    Open.1    High.1     Low.1   Close.1
2016-01-01 00:01:00        NA       NA        NA        NA  98.37414  99.96370  90.72532  92.95577
2016-01-01 00:02:00  96.81493 103.8074  96.48305  99.31684  93.98500  93.98500  73.69129  80.18034
2016-01-01 00:03:00 100.31574 100.9088  95.27193  95.27193        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:04:00  95.11235 105.5243  95.11235 105.41863  76.43040  78.95213  65.05842  65.61655
2016-01-01 00:05:00 105.85303 117.9486 104.51442 117.94861  64.99275  75.81193  63.17524  74.69825
2016-01-01 00:06:00 118.60936 121.7275 116.02890 118.76587  72.37924  83.95192  72.37924  83.95192
2016-01-01 00:07:00 118.96981 119.5623 111.49401 118.46579        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:08:00        NA       NA        NA        NA  81.29073  83.81830  75.01105  80.61681
2016-01-01 00:09:00        NA       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:10:00 115.68374 115.6837 102.88741 108.07260        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:12:00 101.51486 102.4733  97.82271  99.14294 106.27114 109.24152  98.20000 102.32379
2016-01-01 00:13:00  98.81746 103.8946  90.79351 103.89463        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:15:00 100.47314 100.4731  84.78741  94.06465        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:16:00  94.94257 107.0833  94.12961 102.15526        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:17:00 101.74539 104.1814  92.38105  92.42347 103.73324 109.78397 103.73324 107.02864
                       Open.2    High.2     Low.2   Close.2
2016-01-01 00:01:00  99.85170 109.91461  99.85170 107.31518
2016-01-01 00:02:00 106.66197 115.44153 104.47501 109.24811
2016-01-01 00:03:00 110.84442 118.38943 110.83901 113.95159
2016-01-01 00:04:00 114.71170 118.63914 107.73243 114.53394
2016-01-01 00:05:00        NA        NA        NA        NA
2016-01-01 00:06:00 106.73027 108.71359 101.05015 101.42198
2016-01-01 00:07:00  99.97737 110.32388  98.99063 106.02683
2016-01-01 00:08:00 105.86289 114.69850 103.34898 110.09985
2016-01-01 00:09:00 110.25313 111.33632  99.71466 111.33632
2016-01-01 00:10:00 112.03636 117.08576 111.28522 111.69231
2016-01-01 00:12:00  93.97850 100.14015  83.35741  83.35741
2016-01-01 00:13:00  82.28654  89.93466  81.26308  85.61102
2016-01-01 00:15:00  82.10802  82.10802  70.98550  74.15053
2016-01-01 00:16:00  74.56891  78.30949  73.06504  77.90111
2016-01-01 00:17:00        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

**The question** is :  how do I now return each `xts` object back to the `list`

===========
`My_list` creation code

```
make_sec <- function(){
  
Time <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"), length = 1000, by = "sec")
Price <- cumsum(rnorm(1000))+100

Sec <- xts(Price, order.by = Time) |> 
           to_period(period = "minutes", k = 1) |>
           align.time()

colnames(Sec) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close")

# Sec with not all timestamps
Sec[-sample(1:nrow(Sec),size = sample(3:10,1)),]
}
n <- 3 # can be any number
My_list <- lapply(1:n, function(x) make_sec())
names(My_list) <- paste0("Sec",1:length(My_list))
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `c(list(do.call(merge, My_list)), My_list)`? If not, please clarify what you mean by *"return each xts object back to the list"*.

Comment: Hello! no, this is not what i need .... I need each 'xts' object to be in its own 'list' cell.
That is, I want the same 'My_list' only after 'megre'

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `xts` to know what that means, tbh, sorry.

Comment: I also do not understand what you want if it is not `c(list(do.call(merge, My_list)), My_list`. The includes the merge result as well as the same `My_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question did not provide the input in an easily reproducible form so we will use `L` in the Note at the end which was created using `dput`.

Also notice that the `merge` in the question loses the original list's names (Sec1, Sec2, Sec3) so to retain them suffix the column names with the corresponding list name first using merge's suffixes= argument.

Given that merged object `M` use `fortify.zoo` to convert to long form, split on the suffixes, convert to zoo and then xts, remove the NA rows and remove the suffixes we added.

```
library(magrittr)
library(tools)
library(xts)

M <- do.call("merge", c(L, list(suffixes = paste("", names(L)))))

L.2 <- M %>%
  fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE) %>%
  split(file_ext(.$Series)) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    x %>%
      read.zoo(split = "Series") %>%
      as.xts %>%
      na.omit %>%
      setNames(file_path_sans_ext(names(.))) %>%
      structure(na.action = NULL)
   })

identical(L, L.2)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

```
L <- list(Sec1 = structure(c(96.81493, 100.31574, 95.11235, 105.85303, 
118.60936, 118.96981, 115.68374, 101.51486, 98.81746, 100.47314, 
94.94257, 101.74539, 103.8074, 100.9088, 105.5243, 117.9486, 
121.7275, 119.5623, 115.6837, 102.4733, 103.8946, 100.4731, 107.0833, 
104.1814, 96.48305, 95.27193, 95.11235, 104.51442, 116.0289, 
111.49401, 102.88741, 97.82271, 90.79351, 84.78741, 94.12961, 
92.38105, 99.31684, 95.27193, 105.41863, 117.94861, 118.76587, 
118.46579, 108.0726, 99.14294, 103.89463, 94.06465, 102.15526, 
92.42347), dim = c(12L, 4L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", 
"High", "Low", "Close")), index = structure(c(1451624520, 1451624580, 
1451624640, 1451624700, 1451624760, 1451624820, 1451625000, 1451625120, 
1451625180, 1451625300, 1451625360, 1451625420), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo")), Sec2 = structure(c(98.37414, 
93.985, 76.4304, 64.99275, 72.37924, 81.29073, 106.27114, 103.73324, 
99.9637, 93.985, 78.95213, 75.81193, 83.95192, 83.8183, 109.24152, 
109.78397, 90.72532, 73.69129, 65.05842, 63.17524, 72.37924, 
75.01105, 98.2, 103.73324, 92.95577, 80.18034, 65.61655, 74.69825, 
83.95192, 80.61681, 102.32379, 107.02864), dim = c(8L, 4L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")), index = structure(c(1451624460, 
1451624520, 1451624640, 1451624700, 1451624760, 1451624880, 1451625120, 
1451625420), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), Sec3 = structure(c(99.8517, 106.66197, 110.84442, 114.7117, 
106.73027, 99.97737, 105.86289, 110.25313, 112.03636, 93.9785, 
82.28654, 82.10802, 74.56891, 109.91461, 115.44153, 118.38943, 
118.63914, 108.71359, 110.32388, 114.6985, 111.33632, 117.08576, 
100.14015, 89.93466, 82.10802, 78.30949, 99.8517, 104.47501, 
110.83901, 107.73243, 101.05015, 98.99063, 103.34898, 99.71466, 
111.28522, 83.35741, 81.26308, 70.9855, 73.06504, 107.31518, 
109.24811, 113.95159, 114.53394, 101.42198, 106.02683, 110.09985, 
111.33632, 111.69231, 83.35741, 85.61102, 74.15053, 77.90111), dim = c(13L, 
4L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")), index = structure(c(1451624460, 
1451624520, 1451624580, 1451624640, 1451624760, 1451624820, 1451624880, 
1451624940, 1451625000, 1451625120, 1451625180, 1451625300, 1451625360
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo")))
```